# Problema con public function__construct()

Tags: php, php7

Mi hija está estudiando PHP en la escuela y le dieron para hacer este ejercicio, pero le da un error en  `public function__construct()`. Si alguien la puede ayudar u orientar, desde ya, muchas gracias

```
<?php

class Adivina {

private $numeroGenerado;
private $numeroElegido;
private $min;
private $max;

public function__construct($min, $max, $numeroElegido) {

    $this->min= $min;
    $this->max= $max;
    $this->numeroElegido= $numeroElegido;
    $this->verificar();
}

public function generarNumero() {
    return $this->numeroGenerado= rand($this->min, $this->max);
}

public function verificar() {
    if($this->numeroElegido > $this->max) {
        echo "El número es mayor al límite <br>";
}

elseif ($this->numeroElegido < $this->min) {
    echo "El número es menor al límite <br>";
}

elseif($this->generarNumero() == $this->numeroElegido) {
    echo "Haz acertado al número <br>";
}
$this->mostrarNumeroGenerado() {
    echo "El número generado es: ". $this->numeroGenerado;
}
 }

}

?>
```

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Taller_PHP\POLITECNICO\diplomado_PHP\POO\Adivina.php on line 10

Comment: Entre function y los dos guiones bajos debe ir un espacio en blanco

Comment: Le falta un espacio `public function __construct()`

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque es error tipográfico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error de sintaxis en la línea 10. El compilador ha encontrado "("
>   cuando esperaba una variable.

PHP indica con "bastante" precisión donde están los errores y el tipo. En este caso, el problema es que escribió:

```
public function__construct(
```

`function` y `__construct` **deben ir separados por un espacio**, sino el compilador no es capaz de interpretar el código, y trata de indicar donde esta el problema y guiarnos acerca de cuál es (si las opciones de *debug* están activadas).